# CSV файл создается с пустыми строками

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть проблемы в следующем - после выполнения Python скрипта, генерируется CSV - файл. Все данные записываются как нужно, только каждая строка разделяется пустой строчкой. Вот код:

```
def write_csv(data):
    with open('file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((data['title'],
                         data['description']))
```

Посмотрев советы, многим помогает замена 'a' на 'w'. Только в моем случае, если поменять эти параметры, файл на выходе получается пустым.

```
def write_csv(data):
        with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow((data['title'],
                             data['description']))
```

Пример данных для data

```
def get_advt(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    advt_pages = soup.find('div', class_='bcatalog-items-wrap').find_all('a', class_='bcatalog-one__name')
    for pr in advt_pages:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html('https://site.ru' + pr.get('href')), 'lxml')
            ads = soup.find('div', class_='bcatalog-inside')
            for ad in ads:
                        try:
                            title = ad.find('h1').text.strip()
                        except:
                            title = ''
                        try:
                            description = ad.find('div', class_='bcatalog-inside__content-full').text.strip()
                        except:
                            description = ''
                        data = {'title':title,
                        'description':description}
                        write_csv(data)
```

Может кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией и поможет советом? Спасибо.

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример данных для `data`

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит прочитать: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и оформить вопрос соответственно. Во первых мы не знаем что найдет ваш код в неизвестном нам HTML. Во вторых, есть подозрение, что функция `write_csv(data)` вызывается в цикле и каждый раз перезаписывает CSV файл. В любом случае те кто хотят вам помочь и ответить на ваш вопрос не должны гадать и тратить свое время на то чтобы задать очередной уточняющий вопрос...

Comment: Какая система? Совет: убрать ``newline=''``.

Comment: Система Windows 10. Если убирать newline='' выводит по 4 пустых строки (с newline, две)